# Como testar vários data.frames e estabelecer uma pontuação máxima dos testes para uma certa posição? #R

Tags: r, data.frame

Considerando os seguintes data.frames:

```
 library(zoo)
 A<-data.frame(x1=(0:9),x2=rep(0:1,5),x3=rep(0:4,2))
 B<-apply(A, 2, function(x) rollapply(x, width = 2, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = 'r', na.rm=TRUE))
 C<-apply(A, 2, function(x) rollapply(x, width = 3, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = 'r', na.rm=TRUE))
 D<-apply(A, 2, function(x) rollapply(x, width = 4, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = 'r', na.rm=TRUE))
```

Sendo que B,C e D são resultado da acumulação dos valores de A, realizada com o emprego da função de janela móvel `rollapply`, variando de um em um de 2 a 4.

Quero testar quando A,B,C e D são iguais, quer dizer, A==B, A==B==C e A==B==C==D. Depois disto, o resultado dos testes deve ser convertido em notas, por exemplo:

```
 Teste       | Nota
 "A==B"      |  1 
 "A==B==C"   |  20
 "A==B==C==D"|  300
```

Armazenando cada nota em um data.frame na sua respectiva posição, como para "A==B":

```
      x1 x2 x3
 [1,] NA NA NA
 [2,]  1  1  1
 [3,]  0  0  0
 [4,]  0  1  0
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,]  0  1  0
 [7,]  0  0  1
 [8,]  0  1  0
 [9,]  0  0  0
[10,]  0  1  0
```

Após a geração de cada nota (data.frame), preciso saber qual a nota máxima para cada célula. Como realizar esse procedimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, o código abaixo faz o que você quer. Mas os dados parecem não ser ideais, porque não tem nenhum caso de `A==B==C` muito menos `A==B==C==D`. Se você tiver dados reais mais apropriados pode ver se funcionou mesmo.

Achei melhor explicar linha a linha do que tudo de uma vez.

```
library(zoo)

A <- data.frame(x1 = (0:9), x2 = rep(0:1, 5), x3 = rep(0:4, 2))

# Colocando todas matrizes acumuladas em uma lista única
BCD <- lapply(setNames(2:4, c("B", "C", "D")), function(i) {
  apply(A, 2, function(x) rollapply(x, width = i, FUN = sum, fill = NA, align = 'r', na.rm=TRUE))
})

# Definindo as notas para cada nível de comparação
notas <- c(1, 20, 300)

# Realizando a comparação de forma recursiva
comps <- lapply(1:3, function(j) {
  # Compara A com todas os elementos de BCD e 1 até j (1:1, 1:2, 1:3)
  equals <- Reduce("==", append(list(A), BCD[1:j]))
  # Coloca a nota em função da comparação
  comp <- ifelse(equals, notas[j], 0)
  # Transforma os NA em 0, depende do que você deseja.
  comp[is.na(comp)] <- 0
  # Retorna comp
  comp
})

# Roda nas matrizes de comps mantendo o máximo de cada posição
all.max <- do.call(pmax, comps)
all.max

#       x1 x2 x3
#  [1,]  0  0  0
#  [2,]  1  1  1
#  [3,]  0  0  0
#  [4,]  0  1  0
#  [5,]  0  0  0
#  [6,]  0  1  0
#  [7,]  0  0  1
#  [8,]  0  1  0
#  [9,]  0  0  0
# [10,]  0  1  0
```

Como eu disse, o resultado só tem notas 1 pois só existe `A==B`.

Comment: @ Funcionou! Estou tento generalizar para casos com mais mais matrizes. Assim que conseguir vou carregar os dados verdadeiros.